# I am trying to store a html table into a pandas dataframe. But I am getting an error, TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'WebElement'

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to store a html table into a pandas dataframe. But I am getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'WebElement'`.

```
    driver.get('web_url')
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody[@id = "treeview-1083-body"]//tr[@id = "treeview-1083-record-ext-record-20"]').click()
    time.sleep(4)
    recording_table = driver.find_element_by_id("table_id")
    df = pd.read_html(recording_table)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse HTML and Read HTML Table with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214702/parse-html-and-read-html-table-with-selenium-python)

Answer (score 2):

The [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) function can read an HTML from a URL, a file-like object, or a raw string containing HTML not an [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html).

You can try to convert this element into raw string. 
To do that, you can get the outer HTML

```
content = recording_table.get_attribute("outerHTML")
pd.read_html(content)
```